# Applying styling to sections based on IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

My question here is two-part. But all relative to understanding more about how the intersection observer works.

I get all my 'sections', loop through and apply the observer to each one. My goal is if the section is intersecting, I want to apply a style, and for the ones that are not intersecting I don't want the style applied. on page load, all my sections have the border and are not toggling as I would expect them to. Also, in my console.log(entry) the entry seems to log before I actually intersect with the section.

**ex:** I am scrolling up and am still clearly in the border of "section 3" but the log for "section 2" has already shown up.

Some help with a general understanding and some possible solutions would be amazing.

```
let allSections = document.querySelectorAll('section')
```

```
const options = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0,
  rootMargin: '0px'
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function
  (entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      console.log('ENTRY', entry.target)
      entry.target.style.border = '1px solid red'
    } else {
      entry.target.style.border = '1px solid transparent'
    }
  })
}, options)

allSections.forEach(section => {
  observer.observe(section)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because of your `options` object, the `threshold` need to be greater than 0 if you wanna see your animation happens.

`threshold: 1` means `entry.isIntersecting` is true when 100% of the element is in the viewport.

`threshold: 0.3` means `entry.isIntersecting` is true when 30% of the element is in the viewport, etc.

```js
const options = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 1,
  rootMargin: '0px'
}
```

If you wanna know more about it, you can read on MDN documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Comment: So I played with that and setting it to about .3 does more of what I want. I am also realizing isIntersecting can be true for multiple objects at the same time. As now I see styles toggling but also applying to two sections if the scroll is in the right spot. Is there any way to have the style be applied to only ONE object at a time?

Comment: That behaviour of having two sections getting animated is happening when the two of them are in the viewport, right ?

Comment: Yes. so perhaps isIntersecting is not the function that I want to use in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately that is how `Intersection Observer` works, it is not about `isIntersecting`.

Comment: So let's assume I set threshold to .5, this will work great for transitioning some sections, but assuming different sections have different heights this will have inconsistent results for what I am trying to do?

Comment: No, it will works fine. The threshold is related individually to each item, so it depends on its own height, wether it is 100vh or 40Opx.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241529/discussion-between-ben-sven-ten-and-yousoumar).